# How do I / Can I access an array inside of an other array in C#

Tags: c#

So my problem is probably that I understand 2d Arrays in C# wrong but I have the following 2d Array:

```
int[,] Input = {
{1, 2, 3},
{4, 5, 6},
{7, 8, 9}
}
```

From my understanding I have 3 Arrays (1,2,3), (4,5,6) and (7,8,9) inside another Array.

I know I can access element 5 with Input[1, 1], but I want to be able to work with each of the 3 smaller Arrays, for example I need the Index of 5 in the Array (4,5,6), wich would be 1. But I just don't get how I can do this.

I thought something like

`int indexOfFive = Array.IndexOf(Input[1], 5);` 
would give me the answer (1) but it doesn't.

Alternatively I tried creating a new Array like this

`int[] newArray = Input[1]`
which in my mind should create a new Array which has the elements of the 2nd Array in Input (4,5,6)

Comment: "From my understanding I have 3 Arrays (1,2,3), (4,5,6) and (7,8,9) inside another Array." This was true if you had a nested array, which is declared via `int[][]`. But `int[,]` is a two-dimensional array.

Comment: "I have 3 Arrays" - no, you have 1 multidimensional array. Sounds like you want [a _jagged_ array (`int[,]` vs. `int[][]`) instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/arrays#jagged-arrays)

Comment: It's nasty, but `Input.Cast<int>().Skip(3).Take(3).ToArray();` will give you [4,5,6]